# Invoking rake with whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, rake-task, whenever

I just started using Rails Whenever plugin. I have rake file cron. with task:

```
task :cron => :environment do
   puts "Task invoked!"
end
```

And in schedule.rb I have this:

```
every 2.minutes do 
   rake "cron", enviroment => "development"
end
```

Once I start my app and specified interval passes, nothing happens? I am pretty new to Ruby and Rails so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write the schedule to your crontab. Run this command in your app:

```
bundle exec whenever --update-crontab myapp
```

When you run this command, `whenever` takes the Ruby syntax, translates it to cron syntax and adds it to your crontab.

Comment: I ran the command that you said and it was executed with no errors... But in the response message I got this in the text:

      && RAILS_ENV=production does this mean that it going to be executed only in production enviroment?

Comment: Try `whenever --update-crontab appname --set environment=development`